# Free particle wavefunction has a carrier and envelope part

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, phase-velocity

If

$\psi(x, t)=\left(\frac{1}{2 \pi \alpha^{2}}\right)^{1 / 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}} e^{i p_{0}\left(x-p_{0} t / 2 m\right) / \hbar} e^{-\left(x-p_{0} t / m\right)^{2} / 4 \alpha^{2} \gamma}$

where

- $\gamma=1+\frac{i t}
  {\tau}$
- $\tau=\frac{m h}{2 \beta^{2}}$

> ... this wave packet has a carrier wave part that is characterized by $p_{0}$ and propagates at the phase velocity $p_{0} / 2\,m$, and an envelope part that is characterized by the momentum width $\beta$ (through the $\alpha$ parameter) and propagates at the group velocity $p_{0} / m$. As we expected, the envelope is a Gaussian function.

I'm not able to understand how the wavefunction has a carrier and an envelope part.

Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

It is constructed according to the wavepacket solution for wave equations.

A simple plane wave, i.e. with one frequency describing the particle, is not localized in space so cannot be used as the probability  base wavefunction of a free particle as it will be equally probable to the particle to be anywhere in space.

The [wavepacket solution](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Waves/wpack.html)   allows space localization and normalizing to 1 the probability of finding the particle in a specific (x,y,z,t). A simple function:

[image]

The envelope in your more complicated formula is the envelope seen above, space localization of the probability distribution when taking $Ψ^*Ψ$.

Comment: I've tried extracting the real part but the number of terms becomes too large to visualize the envelope and carrier. Both the exponentials are complex ,also the coefficient is complex so that's three complex multiplicative terms I've to split into real and imaginary parts and then see the envelope and carrier wave

Comment: maybe this will help https://web1.eng.famu.fsu.edu/~dommelen/quantum/style_a/packets.html

Comment: @Kashmiri:  To see that the magnitude will be a Gaussian, split the expression for $\psi$ into three parts:  the coefficients in front, the first exponential, and the second exponential.  The magnitude-squared of the first one will be proportional to $1/\sqrt{\gamma \gamma^*}$, which is independent of $x$.  The magnitude squared of the first exponential will be 1.  And the magnitude squared of the second exponential will be $$\exp \left[ - \frac{(x-p_{0} t / m)^{2}}{4 \alpha^{2}} \left( \frac{1}{\gamma} + \frac{1}{\gamma^*} \right) \right]$$ which will be a Gaussian centered at $p_0 t/m$.